# PostgreSQL error: could not receive data from client: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: postgresql, startup, antivirus

PostgreSQL version 9.1.3.  OS is Windows XP.  Anti-virus is F-Secure. Six instances of postgres.exe are running.

Here's what's in the pg_log:

```
2012-04-08 14:58:23 PDT LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2012-04-08 14:58:24 PDT LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2012-04-08 14:58:24 PDT LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2012-04-08 14:58:25 PDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.

2012-04-08 14:58:25 PDT LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2012-04-08 14:58:27 PDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.
```

I disabled F-Secure but it made no difference. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not unusual for antivirus products to cause problems even when stopped or disabled.  They must sometimes be completely uninstalled to avoid having them get in the way of normal database operations.  Another likely possibility is that there is a firewall which needs to be configured to allow the TCP server socket to be opened or the UDP socket used by the various PostgreSQL processes to communicate regarding statistics.