# failed to connect to postgres server

Tags: java, postgresql, maven

I have a strange issue. Until 2 days back, my setup has been working for almost 2 years. 
the setup that always worked :

```
1. I use postgress 9.3 for development on my laptop. 
2. I use intellij idea database tools to browse data
3. sometimes I use pgadmin
4. I run maven build of our application
```

for the past 2 days, when I run maven install , build fails with

```
[main] ERROR SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(146) | Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The connection attempt failed.)
```

but, my idea client,  pgadmin have no problem connecting.

### pg log has the following :

```
2015-11-06 11:08:02 CST LOG:  could not receive data from client: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.


2015-11-06 11:08:02 CST LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2015-11-06 11:08:17 CST LOG:  could not receive data from client: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.


2015-11-06 11:08:17 CST LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2015-11-06 11:08:35 CST WARNING:  pgstat wait timeout
2015-11-06 11:08:46 CST WARNING:  pgstat wait timeout
2015-11-06 11:09:35 CST WARNING:  pgstat wait timeout
2015-11-06 11:09:45 CST WARNING:  pgstat wait timeout
```

I also disabled firewall and tried. It still fails.

any hints on what could be happening ?

Comment: and you have eliminated the possibility that:    1) - the connection params in your code/test were changed (user, pwd, etc),     2) - the db to which you are connecting still has that user/pwd.    Just to be sure, compare the user/pwd in your IDE config with the ones your build uses. If different, setup a connection in IDE with the same credentials and see if that works.

Comment: yes. first thing I have not changed any of the db settings. secondly, the build is passing through some modules (which would require db access) and fails in a subsequent module.

Comment: Critical details missing. Windows version? (The error clearly suggests this is Windows). PostgreSQL version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like something's wrong with the windows TCP/IP stack.

See:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/817571
- [PostgreSQL error: could not receive data from client: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067024/398670)
- The mailing list thread http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTimgyax1LUU85caP2FfwKTWkdAwDIE3S7zI-6oea@mail.gmail.com

Possible actions include:

- **Completely uninstall** your antivirus product or (worse) "internet security" suite if you have one. Disabling it is *not* likely to be enough. You can reinstall or install a better one once you've confirmed it's the cause.
- Do a [windows TCP/IP stack reset](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299357). Exact steps depend on your Windows version, which you did not mention, so you might need to look around a bit. This might have side effects like clearing settings that break other applications. You should know what you're doing, be willing to accept possible problems, or get professional support from a tech with Windows skills.
- Check the system for possible rootkit or undetected virus activity
- Uninstall any unnecessary drivers for 3G modems, cable providers, etc
- If you installed any software recently, remove it

Comment: a lot of problems started after I installed thunderbird. I kept on blindly accepting during installation and a bunch of stuff got in. Now, port 8080 is not available for my application. I changed my dev setup to use a different port . I uninstalled thunderbird , but, some stuff seems to be lingering around.

Comment: @user19937 Maybe you got a dodgy Thunderbird installer from a 3rd party source, bundled with malware or unrelated garbage? Don't download from SourceForge, they've started bundling crapware.

Comment: Looks like it. I cannot imagine official bundle to have caused this.